# Castle Nvelocity GetTemplate method won't work

Tags: c#, nvelocity

I've been trying to follow [this](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/usingit.html) instructions to implement email templating using NVelocity but I keep getting a resource not found exception from the GetTemplate method.

I've used Server.MapPath full routes and also relative routes and haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the version of the NVelocity assembly I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention Server.MapPath, I'm going to guess that this is for a web page.  In case, is this in a MonoRail Website?  If so, then there are methods on the Controller object for sending emails from a webpage, which make it much simpler (and the templates go in Views/email folder.)

Comment: I want to use it to merge templates.